# Product over a factorial convergences

Tags: convergence-divergence

I'm working on a problem and need this to converge to any value:

$\displaystyle \frac{(1/2)((1/2)-1)((1/2)-2)\cdots ((1/2)-n+1)}{(n+1)!} = \Pi_{j=1}^{n} \frac{\frac{1}{2} - j+1}{j+1}$

The convergence is evident when you begin doing the product. However, if there a way to prove this?

By the way, I do not know pi notation for products yet.

Comment: \Pi_{i=m}^n a_i gives $\Pi_{i=m}^n a_i$

Comment: Do you know the gamma function ?

Comment: @vadim123 Indeed, I noticed I had done a mistake in the transcription (since I don't know mathjax, I had copied an online template). I just fixed it.

Comment: This is related to the binomial coefficient $\binom{1/2}{n}$.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici unfortunately, I do not. This is part of a bonus question on my homework, so my prof must expect us to find things ourselves.

Comment: If I am reading this correctly, there are $n$ factors in the numerator and $n+1$ factors in the denominator. For each term in the numerator, find a factor in the denominator that is just about the same size or maybe a little larger. This part of the product would therefore not become very large. Then look at the one term that is remaining in the denominator. What does this do to the product? The answer should now pop out at you.

Comment: In any manner, I was not reading your expression correctly.